# converting to little endian with less digits

Tags: math, endianness

Little endian is pretty simply when you look at something like: `0x8048cc54 -> \x54\xcc\x48\x80`. What about 0x8048cc4 or 0x8048cc if you want to convert these to 8 bytes how would you do it. If this is the wrong forum for this just let me know and ill move it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on the container (memory size) of your values. If (like in the first example) the value is treated as 32 bit, you only need to look at it's "full scope":

```
0x8048cc4 == 0x08048cc4
0x8048cc  == 0x008048cc
```

From here the answer to convert endianess is simple...

Comment: You're welcome. If you find the answer useful, I'd appreciate an up vote as well.

Answer (score 1):

"Endianness" is just the order you write your digits.

Most of the world writes things in big endian; the most significant digit comes first, continuing to the least signficant last:

123 = 100 + 20 + 3 (= 1×10² + 2×10¹ + 3×10⁰)

From a computer's perspective, however, it is often useful to look at it from the other end:

321 = 3 + 02 + 001 (= 3×10⁰ + 2×10¹ + 1×10²)

The 'digits' of a number in a computer are composed of the values 0..255 -- that is, each digit is a single byte. We humans don't have 256 different symbols to write that byte value, so we convert it from base 256 to base 16.

To write it in little endian, start at the least significant byte and peel off until you run out of bytes/digits:

0x0848cc4 --> \xc4\x8c\x84\x00

0x8048cc --> \xcc\x48\x80\x00

Hope this helps.